# How to extract a piece of string from vold.fstab

Tags: android, string, android-sdcard

I want to know how can I extract the `sdcard` path from the `vold.fstab` file in android phones.

```
dev_mount sdcard /storage/extSdCard auto/
devices/aform/msm_sdcc.3/mmc_host/
mmc1/
```

How do I extract the `/storage/extSdCard` only?

Answer (score 0):

Please don't parse vold.fstab, it's an internal implementation detail of the platform, and it may change between releases.  You should only rely on public APIs like `Context.getExternalCacheDirs()`.